# Perl table Extract or other method for multi page table

Tags: html, perl

I'm trying to extract elements from a table, I have successfully used get and HTML:TableExtract to get elements of the table. The problem is the table is multi page and navigated with an arrow button to show additional pages. How would i extract these other pages as they are not new links but I think generated with JS or such?

Specifically I am trying to extract the table under Data for this Data Range at:

http://ycharts.com/companies/GOOG/pe_ratio#series=type:company,id:GOOG,calc:pe_ratio,,id:AAPL,type:company,calc:pe_ratio,,id:AMZN,type:company,calc:pe_ratio&zoom=3&startDate=&endDate=&format=real&recessions=false

See how there is the Viewing x of 45 and the First, Previous, Next, Last button.

The rest of the table elements can be viewed with next, how would i extract these in perl?

Update::
Hi Simbabque, Thanks for the response.
So I see if you click on next it calls:
ng-click="getHistoricalData(historicalData.currentPage+1)"

Is there a way I can call this method? I tried to use click,but it is not bound a name. (JS?)

I was trying to use Mechanize::Firefox now but I feel like their must be an easy way to use regular Mech and call the function and re-read the page?

Comment: Please use the comments to reply to answers. Do not edit your replies into your question. Read the [faq] if you need help on how Stack Overflow works. With WWW::Mechanize you cannot execute any Javascript. No calling that function.

Answer (score 1):

The website builds up the tables using AJAX requests. Those are a little harder to parse. You can use [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) to fetch the initial page and then hit the AJAX calls for the table. It helps you keep track of cookies and stuff automatically.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get('http://ycharts.com/companies/GOOG/pe_ratio#series=type:company,id:GOOG,calc:pe_ratio,,id:AAPL,type:company,calc:pe_ratio,,id:AMZN,type:company,calc:pe_ratio&zoom=3&startDate=&endDate=&format=real&recessions=false');

my $response = $mech->post(
  'http://ycharts.com/companies/GOOG/pe_ratio/data_ajax',
  {
    startDate => '1/1/1962',
    endDate   => '12/3/2013',
    pageNum   => 4,
  }
);

if ( $response->is_success ) {
  print $response->decoded_content;    # or whatever
} else {
  die $response->status_line;
}
```

This is just a basic example and will not work. It gives a `403 Forbidden`. Probably there is more data required. Use Firebug or a similar tool to inspect what is happening. For example, there's another call to `http://ping.chartbeat.net/ping?h=ycharts.com&p=%2Fcompanies%2FGOOG%2Fpe_ratio&u=o3m6snxteynby1b8&d=ycharts.com&g=20054&n=1&f=00001&c=10.81&x=200&y=1812&o=1663&w=658&j=30&R=0&W=1&I=0&E=109&e=6&b=1903&t=usmc0fjfd1j0h87g&V=16&_` happening automatically every now and again, with varying parameters. That is most likely required to keep the session going.

This page is pretty sophisticated. This might not be the best approach.

You could also try to use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox or even Selenium to remote-operate a browser. That will be better suited as it takes care of all the AJAX stuff that is happening.

Or you could look for a public API that just hands over that data voluntarily. I bet there is one around... or just pay for a ycharts pro account and hit the download button. ;-)